# Associative array containing objects, each containing an array, filling with variable names instead of the values

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have an object I've made

```
class SalesReportObject
{
    public $eventname = "";
    public $v_firstname = "";
    public $v_secondname = "";
    public $soldStock = array();
    function Push($productname, $soldquantity)
    {
        $soldStock[$productname] = $soldquantity;
    }
    function Sum($productname, $soldquantity)
    {
        $soldStock[$productname] += $soldquantity;
    }
    function __construct($e, $f, $s)
    {
        $eventname = $e;
        $v_firstname = $f;
        $v_secondname = $s;
    }

}
```

And I'm populating it using the following

```
$salesreportq = 'SELECT Volunteers.SecondName, Volunteers.FirstName, Events.EventName, ItemIssue.Quantity, ItemIssue.ReturnQuantity, Stock.ProductName, EventInstance.InstanceID 
             FROM EventInstance
             INNER JOIN Events ON EventInstance.EventID = Events.EventID
             INNER JOIN ItemIssue ON EventInstance.InstanceID = ItemIssue.InstanceID 
             INNER JOIN Volunteers ON EventInstance.VolunteerID = Volunteers.VolunteerID 
             INNER JOIN Stock ON ItemIssue.StockID = Stock.StockID
             WHERE (ItemIssue.Returned = ?)';
$yes = array('Yes');                 
$salesreportres = sqlsrv_query($conn, $salesreportq, $yes);
$arr = array();

while ($sRow = sqlsrv_fetch_array($salesreportres, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $sold = $sRow['Quantity'] - $sRow['ReturnQuantity'];

    if (array_key_exists($sRow['InstanceID'], $arr))
    {

        if (array_key_exists($arr[$sRow['InstanceID']]->$soldStock['ProductName']))
        {
            $arr['InstanceID']->Sum($sRow['InstanceID'], $sold);
        }
        else
        {
            $arr['InstanceID']->Push($sRow['InstanceID'], $sold);
        }
    }
    else
    {   
        $arr['InstanceID'] = new SalesReportObject($sRow['EventName'], $sRow['FirstName'], $sRow['SecondName']);
        $arr['InstanceID']->Push($sRow['InstanceID'], $sold);
    }

}
```

Which seems to mostly work, when I print_r() it I get

```
Array ( [InstanceID] => SalesReportObject Object ( [eventname] => [v_firstname] => [v_secondname] => [soldStock] => Array ( ) ) )
```

As you can see it has filled it with variable names of the object instead of the intended values.
It's probably something really dumb, but I can't see it (been at this for a while today)

My question is why is this happening and what do I need to amend?
Thanks in advance for your advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reference your class properties with `$this`. Replace your class code with this:

```
class SalesReportObject
{
    public $eventname = "";
    public $v_firstname = "";
    public $v_secondname = "";
    public $soldStock = array();

    function Push($productname, $soldquantity)
    {
        $this->soldStock[$productname] = $soldquantity;

    }

    function Sum($productname, $soldquantity)
    {
        $this->soldStock[$productname] += $soldquantity;
    }

    function __construct($e, $f, $s)
    {
        $this->eventname = $e;
        $this->v_firstname = $f;
        $this->v_secondname = $s;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm now getting 
Notice: Undefined variable: eventname in C:\RDEUsers\NET\470585\reports.php on line 38

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\RDEUsers\NET\470585\reports.php on line 38

Comment: What's in the line 38?

Comment: $this->$eventname = $e;

Comment: I apologise for not mentioning what was on that line in the first comment, forgot you wouldn't just know somehow haha

Comment: Take a second look at my posted code, `eventname` isn't preceded by a `$` symbol. Actually properties aren't preceded by a `$` symbol when they're accessed by `this`.

Comment: array(1) { [9]=> object(SalesReportObject)#1 (4) { ["eventname"]=> string(10) "Hedon Fair" ["v_firstname"]=> string(4) "Fred" ["v_secondname"]=> string(10) "Flintstone" ["soldStock"]=> array(1) { [9]=> int(15) } } } is my new output, they still seem to be getting variable names in there

Comment: That's because those are the properties of the class. What's your expected output? Please edit your post mentioning what you're expecting to get.

Comment: Ah I see, I've never dealt with a data structure like this in PHP so reading it was a bit confusing. I think i've got it going well now, and the output seems to be what I want, but I'm getting Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\RDEUsers\NET\470585\reports.php on line 34

Comment: Line 34 being $this->soldStock[$productname] += $soldquantity;

Comment: Ignore me, it was another dumb error. Thank you very much for your time and patience with me, you've been a great help @Eduardo Galván